# Send email with file attachment in aura component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, attachment, singleemailmessage

I have an aura component and I want to send email with attachment. The files gets added to the record but it doesn't gets attached to the email. The email is send without any attachment.

Component:

```
<aura:component controller="TT_EmailMessageController" implements="force:hasRecordId,force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,lightning:actionOverride,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickActionwithoutHeader">
   
    <aura:attribute name="email" type="string"/> 
    <aura:attribute name="emailCC" type="string"/>
    <aura:attribute name="emailBCC" type="string"/>
    <aura:attribute name="subject" type="string"/>
    <aura:attribute name="bodytext" type="string"/>
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />
    <aura:attribute name="showComponent" type="Boolean"/>
    <aura:attribute name="showSendButton" type="Boolean"/>
    <aura:attribute name="options" type="List"/>
    <aura:attribute name="selectedValueEmail" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="emailTemplates" type="List"/>
    <aura:attribute name="selectedEmailTemplate" type="String"/>
    
    <aura:attribute name="filetype" type="List" default="['.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.doc', '.docx', '.pdf', '.xlsx']" />
    
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>     

    <div class="slds-m-around–medium" id="mainDiv">
       <div class="slds-container–medium">
          <div class="slds-form–stacked">
             <div class="slds-form-element">
                <label class="slds-form-element__label left_margin text_bold">To</label>
                <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                   <ui:inputEmail class="slds-input left_margin" aura:id="email"  value="{!v.email}" required="true" />
                </div>
             </div>
             <div class="slds-form-element">
               <label class="slds-form-element__label left_margin text_bold">From</label>
               <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                  <!-- <ui:inputEmail class="slds-input left_margin input_width" aura:id="email"  value="{!v.email}" required="true" placeholder="enter@email.com"/> -->
                  <lightning:select name="colorId" aura:id="colorId" value="{!v.selectedValueEmail}" class="left_margin">
                     <aura:iteration items="{!v.options}" var="option">
                         <option text="{!option.label}" value="{!option.value}" />
                     </aura:iteration>
                 </lightning:select>
               </div>
             </div>
             <div class="slds-form-element">
               <label class="slds-form-element__label left_margin text_bold">CC</label>
               <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                  <ui:inputEmail class="slds-input left_margin" aura:id="email"  value="{!v.emailCC}"/>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-form-element">
               <label class="slds-form-element__label left_margin text_bold">BCC</label>
               <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                  <ui:inputEmail class="slds-input left_margin" aura:id="email"  value="{!v.emailBCC}"/>
               </div>
            </div>
             <div class="slds-form-element">
                <label class="slds-form-element__label left_margin text_bold">Subject</label>
                <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                   <ui:inputText class="slds-input left_margin" aura:id="subject"  value="{!v.subject}" placeholder="Subject"/>
                </div>
             </div>
             <div class="slds-form-element">
                <label class="slds-form-element__label left_margin text_bold">Email Body</label>
                <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                   <lightning:inputRichText  aura:id="body" value="{!v.bodytext}" />
                </div>
             </div>
            <div class="slds-form-element"> 
            <lightning:fileUpload label="Attach files"
                    name="fileUploader"
                    multiple="true"
                    accept="{!v.filetype}"
                    recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                    onuploadfinished="{!c.handleUploadFinished}" />
             </div>
             <div class="slds-form-element left_margin display_flex">    
                <lightning:select name="colorId" aura:id="colorId" label="Select template" value="{!v.selectedEmailTemplate}" onchange="{!c.changeTemplate}" class="left_margin">
                  <aura:iteration items="{!v.emailTemplates}" var="option">
                      <option text="{!option.Name}" value="{!option.Name}" />
                  </aura:iteration>
                </lightning:select>
             </div>
              <div class="slds-form-element">
              <lightning:button class="margin_top_bottom" variant="brand" label="Send" onclick="{!c.sendMail}" />
              <lightning:button class="margin_top_bottom" variant="brand-outline" label="Cancel" onclick="{!c.cancelMail}" />
              </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Controller (js):

```
({
    doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.doInitHelper(component);
    },
    changeTemplate: function(component,event,helper){
        helper.changeTemplateHelper(component,event);
    },
    sendMail: function(component, event, helper) {
    
        var toEmail = component.get("v.email");
        var getSubject = component.get("v.subject");
        var getbody = component.get("v.bodytext");
        var ttCaseRecordId = component.get("v.recordId");
        var emailCC = component.get("v.emailCC");
        var emailBCC = component.get("v.emailBCC");
        var fromEmail = component.get("v.selectedValue");
           
        if ($A.util.isEmpty(toEmail) || !toEmail.includes("@")) {
            alert('Please Enter valid Email Address');
        } else {
            helper.sendEmailHelper(component, event, helper,toEmail, getSubject, getbody,ttCaseRecordId,emailCC, emailBCC, fromEmail );
        }
    },
    cancelMail: function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.cancelMailHelper(component, event, helper);
    },
    
    handleUploadFinished: function (component, event, helper) {
        helper.handleUploadFinishedHelper(component, event, helper);
    },
})
```

Helper (js):

```
({
    sendEmailHelper: function(component,event,helper, toEmail, emailSubject, emailBody,recordId, emailCC, emailBCC, fromEmail) {
        var action = component.get("c.sendEmail");
        action.setParams({
            'toEmailAddress': toEmail,
            'emailSubject': emailSubject,
            'emailBody': emailBody,
            'ttCaseRecordId':recordId,
            'emailCC':emailCC,
            'emailBCC':emailBCC,
            'fromEmail':fromEmail,
        });
        
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                this.showToast('Success','Email has been sent successfully!','success');
                component.set('v.showComponent', false);
                component.set('v.showSendButton', true);
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
    
    cancelMailHelper : function(component,event,helper){
        component.set('v.showComponent', false);
        component.set('v.showSendButton', true);
    },
    
    doInitHelper : function(component){
        var action = component.get("c.loadEmailsAndTempaltes");
    
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                var privateEmail = response.getReturnValue().emails;
                var templates = response.getReturnValue().emailTemplates;
                component.set('v.options', privateEmail);
                component.set('v.emailTemplates', templates);
            }
            
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
    changeTemplateHelper: function(component,event) {
        var allTemplates = component.get('v.emailTemplates');
        var selectedTemplate = component.get('v.selectedEmailTemplate');
        for(let i=0;i<allTemplates.length;i++){
            if(allTemplates[i].Name == selectedTemplate){
                component.set('v.subject', allTemplates[i].Subject);
                if(!$A.util.isUndefinedOrNull(allTemplates[i].HtmlValue)){
                    component.set('v.bodytext', allTemplates[i].HtmlValue);
                }
                else{
                    component.set('v.bodytext', allTemplates[i].Body);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    },    
    showToast : function(title, message, type) {
        var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
        toastEvent.setParams({
            "title": title,
            "message": message,
            "type":type
        });
        toastEvent.fire();
    },
    
    handleUploadFinishedHelper: function(component,event,helper) {
        //Get the list of uploaded files
        var uploadedFiles = event.getParam("files");
        //Show success message – with no of files uploaded
        var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
        toastEvent.setParams({
            "title": "Success!",
            "type" : "success",
            "message": uploadedFiles.length+" files has been uploaded successfully!"
        });
        toastEvent.fire();
         
        $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
         
        //Close the action panel
        var dismissActionPanel = $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction");
        dismissActionPanel.fire();
    }
})
```

Apex class:

```
public with sharing class TT_EmailMessageController {
    
    @AuraEnabled 
    public static void sendEmail(String toEmailAddress ,
                                 String emailSubject ,
                                 String emailBody,
                                 String ttCaseRecordId, 
                                 String emailCC, 
                                 String emailBCC, 
                                 String fromEmail ){
       
        try {
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage singleEmail = createEmail(toEmailAddress, emailBody, emailSubject, ttCaseRecordId, emailCC, emailBCC);
            insertTTEmailMessage(toEmailAddress, fromEmail, emailSubject, emailBody, ttCaseRecordId, emailCC, emailBCC);
            Messaging.SendEmailResult[] result = Messaging.sendEmail(new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>{singleEmail});     
            system.debug(result);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.debug('Query Issue: ' + e);
        } 
    }
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public static DataWrapper loadEmailsAndTempaltes(){
        List<Map<String, String>> items = new List<Map<String, String>>();
        for (OrgWideEmailAddress owa : [SELECT Id, Address, DisplayName 
                                        FROM OrgWideEmailAddress 
                                        WHERE DisplayName = 'UK TTT']) 
        {
            items.add(new Map<String, String>{'value' => owa.Id, 'label' => owa.Address});
        }
        
        List<EmailTemplate> templates = [SELECT Id, Name, Body, Subject, HTMLValue FROM EmailTemplate ];
        List<EmailTemplate> emailTemplates = new List<EmailTemplate>();
        for(EmailTemplate singleTemplate : templates){
            emailTemplates.add(singleTemplate);
        }
        return new DataWrapper(items, emailTemplates);
    }
    
    private static void insertTTEmailMessage(String toEmailAddress, String fromEmailAddress, String subject, String body, String ttCaseId, String cc, String bcc){
        Tender_Tracker_Email_Message__c ttEmailMessage = new Tender_Tracker_Email_Message__c();
        ttEmailMessage.From__c = fromEmailAddress;
        ttEmailMessage.To_Address__c = toEmailAddress;
        ttEmailMessage.From_Name__c = UserInfo.getName();
        ttEmailMessage.Subject__c = subject;
        ttEmailMessage.HTML_Body__c = body;
        ttEmailMessage.Incoming__c = False;
        ttEmailMessage.T_Case__c = ttCaseId;
        ttEmailMessage.CC_Address__c = cc;
        ttEmailMessage.BCC_Address__c = bcc;
            
        insert ttEmailMessage;
    }
    
    private static Messaging.SingleEmailMessage createEmail(String toEmailAddress, String body, String subject, String ttCaseId, String ccEmail, String bccEmail){

        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        String refNumber = '';
        String addrUrl = 'case_email_service@1mu67mpnl.25.cs80.apex.sandbox.salesforce.com';        
        List<String> sendTo = toEmailAddress.split(',');
        mail.setToAddresses(sendTo);        
        mail.setReplyTo(addrUrl);
        mail.setSenderDisplayName('UK TT');  
        mail.setHtmlBody(body);
        if(!subject.contains('[Ref number:')){
            refNumber = ' [Ref number: '+ ttCaseId +']';
        }
        mail.setSubject(subject + refNumber );
        if(String.isNotBlank(ccEmail)){
            mail.ccaddresses = ccEmail.split(',');
        } 
        if(String.isNotBlank(bccEmail)){
            mail.bccaddresses = bccEmail.split(',');
        }      
        return mail;  
    }
    
    public class DataWrapper{
        @AuraEnabled
        public List<Map<String, String>> emails = new List<Map<String, String>>();
        @AuraEnabled
        public List<EmailTemplate> emailTemplates = new List <EmailTemplate>();
        public DataWrapper(List<Map<String, String>> emailsParam, List<EmailTemplate> emailTemplatesParam){
            emails = emailsParam;
            emailTemplates = emailTemplatesParam;
        }
    }   
}
```